# How to record RTMPT stream which keeps disconnecting with VLC?

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, video-streaming, recording, rtmp

I am using VLC to record this stream:

```
rtmpt://164.100.169.57/livepkgr/lok
```

However, the stream stop abruptly after a few minutes of recording in VLC (never lasting more than 12 minutes).

On the other hand, the website where the stream is hosted, broadcasts this stream uninterrupted. I could watch the stream continuously for 30 minutes.

Earlier, the website used to broadcast rtmp stream which was never problematic.

Has anyone else faced this issue with RTMP streams?

How can I record this stream uninterrupted, just as the website broadcasts it uninterrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this utility called RTMPdump. It did the trick. It handled the stream smoothly, without a hitch, unlike VLC.

Answer (score 1):

How about using ffmpeg for recording instead, and VLC for playback?

```
ffmpeg -i "rtmpt://164.100.169.57/livepkgr/lok" -f flv test.flv
```

or for a 60 second sample:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtmpt://164.100.169.57/livepkgr/lok" -f flv -t 60 test.flv
```

Comment: Hello @Jal !
I tried your commands with ffmpeg.exe. They returned the error: 

"Closing connection: NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound
rtmpt://164.100.169.57/livepkgr/lok: Unknown error occurred"

However, the stream is up...it's working with VLC. Could you please suggest a solution? Which files do we need for this command to work? I tried with ffmpeg.exe